# Unknown entry point for Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry

My Nigerian employee is currently here in Canada on a student visa. Soon, he will be assisting me on a trip that **might** look like Barcelona, Nice, Rome then cruise to Greece. We are however early in the planning stage. That said, it is not sure if Barcelona will be the *first entry point*. As the planning moves forward, this might change.

As he needs to apply for his Schengen visa now, what should he put for his *first entry point*? What if it changes?

Further details are that on this trip he will be working for me, a born Canadian citizen. He will never be travelling alone.

Comment: Make sure he has a Canadian status that allows multiple entries into Canada also... returning from a "business trip" on a study permit may lead to some questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Important is to determine the country for the **main purpose** of the visit.

In most cases the country where you will stay for the longest period. That country will be the country where you make the application.

The first point of entry is only needed in case of a 'tie' situation (you are staying 5 days in each country) or otherwise cannot be determined. The visa application will then be made at that country where you first enter. So enter that point, when making the application.

Minor travel adjustments are expected, so if first point of entry changes, that will cause no problem since it is only needed during the initial visa application.

Care should be taken to avoid changing the country for the **main purpose** of the visit.

Comment: That's a very good answer.

Comment: What if my longest stay or pupose of the trip is a cruise leaving from Rome to Greece?

Comment: @QuesnelJ If no main destination can be determined, then the country of entry. The cruise should be meantioned as the reason this cannot be determined.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are all so helpfull and amazing. Thanks for quick response.